# React-Table giving an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier in propTypes.js

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, webpack, react-proptypes, react-table

I've been experiencing an issue with the React-Table library, where Google Chrome show an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier on the first line of the 'prop-Types.js' (`import PropTypes from 'prop-types'`).

I'm running the following versions of related packages:
React: 16.2.0
React-Table: 6.8.0
Prop-Types: 15.6.1

Here is the code from my file where I call `react-table`:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import ReactTable from "react-table";

import { Tips } from "./Utils";
import "react-table/react-table.css";

class SmartGridTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.renderEditable = this.renderEditable.bind(this);
  }

  renderEditable(header, cellInfo){
    return(
      <input key={cellInfo.original.PartId + header + cellInfo.value} defaultValue={cellInfo.value} onBlur={(e) => {this.props.updateRecord(e, cellInfo.original)}} data-field={header}/>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { records, columns } = this.props;
    let tableColumns = columns.map((col) => {
      return {
        Header: col.DisplayName,
        accessor: col.Name,
        Cell: this.renderEditable.bind(null, col.Name)
      }
    })
    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable
          data={records}
          columns={tableColumns}
          defaultPageSize={25}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />
        <Tips />
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SmartGridTable;
```

and here is the propTypes.js file from the react-table library itself (Chrome indicates a syntax problem on the first line):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

export default {
  // General
  data: PropTypes.array,
  loading: PropTypes.bool,
  showPagination: PropTypes.bool,
  showPaginationTop: PropTypes.bool,
  showPaginationBottom: PropTypes.bool,
  showPageSizeOptions: PropTypes.bool,
  pageSizeOptions: PropTypes.array,
  defaultPageSize: PropTypes.number,
  showPageJump: PropTypes.bool,
  collapseOnSortingChange: PropTypes.bool,
  collapseOnPageChange: PropTypes.bool,
  collapseOnDataChange: PropTypes.bool,
  freezeWhenExpanded: PropTypes.bool,
  sortable: PropTypes.bool,
  resizable: PropTypes.bool,
  filterable: PropTypes.bool,
  defaultSortDesc: PropTypes.bool,
  defaultSorted: PropTypes.array,
  defaultFiltered: PropTypes.array,
  defaultResized: PropTypes.array,
  defaultExpanded: PropTypes.object,
  defaultFilterMethod: PropTypes.func,
  defaultSortMethod: PropTypes.func,

  // Controlled State Callbacks
  onPageChange: PropTypes.func,
  onPageSizeChange: PropTypes.func,
  onSortedChange: PropTypes.func,
  onFilteredChange: PropTypes.func,
  onResizedChange: PropTypes.func,
  onExpandedChange: PropTypes.func,

  // Pivoting
  pivotBy: PropTypes.array,

  // Key Constants
  pivotValKey: PropTypes.string,
  pivotIDKey: PropTypes.string,
  subRowsKey: PropTypes.string,
  aggregatedKey: PropTypes.string,
  nestingLevelKey: PropTypes.string,
  originalKey: PropTypes.string,
  indexKey: PropTypes.string,
  groupedByPivotKey: PropTypes.string,

  // Server-side Callbacks
  onFetchData: PropTypes.func,

  // Classes
  className: PropTypes.string,
  style: PropTypes.object,

  // Component decorators
  getProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTableProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadGroupProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadGroupTrProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadGroupThProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadTrProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadThProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadFilterProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadFilterTrProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTheadFilterThProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTbodyProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTrGroupProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTrProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTdProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTfootProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTfootTrProps: PropTypes.func,
  getTfootTdProps: PropTypes.func,
  getPaginationProps: PropTypes.func,
  getLoadingProps: PropTypes.func,
  getNoDataProps: PropTypes.func,
  getResizerProps: PropTypes.func,

  // Global Column Defaults
  columns: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      // Renderers
      Cell: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.element,
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func,
      ]),
      Header: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.element,
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func,
      ]),
      Footer: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.element,
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func,
      ]),
      Aggregated: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.element,
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func,
      ]),
      Pivot: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.element,
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func,
      ]),
      PivotValue: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.element,
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func,
      ]),
      Expander: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.element,
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.func,
      ]),
      Filter: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.element, PropTypes.func]),

      // All Columns
      sortable: PropTypes.bool, // use table default
      resizable: PropTypes.bool, // use table default
      filterable: PropTypes.bool, // use table default
      show: PropTypes.bool,
      minWidth: PropTypes.number,

      // Cells only
      className: PropTypes.string,
      style: PropTypes.object,
      getProps: PropTypes.func,

      // Pivot only
      aggregate: PropTypes.func,

      // Headers only
      headerClassName: PropTypes.string,
      headerStyle: PropTypes.object,
      getHeaderProps: PropTypes.func,

      // Footers only
      footerClassName: PropTypes.string,
      footerStyle: PropTypes.object,
      getFooterProps: PropTypes.object,
      filterMethod: PropTypes.func,
      filterAll: PropTypes.bool,
      sortMethod: PropTypes.func,
    }),
  ),

  // Global Expander Column Defaults
  expanderDefaults: PropTypes.shape({
    sortable: PropTypes.bool,
    resizable: PropTypes.bool,
    filterable: PropTypes.bool,
    width: PropTypes.number,
  }),

  pivotDefaults: PropTypes.object,

  // Text
  previousText: PropTypes.node,
  nextText: PropTypes.node,
  loadingText: PropTypes.node,
  noDataText: PropTypes.node,
  pageText: PropTypes.node,
  ofText: PropTypes.node,
  rowsText: PropTypes.node,

  // Components
  TableComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  TheadComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  TbodyComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  TrGroupComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  TrComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  ThComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  TdComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  TfootComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  FilterComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  ExpanderComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  PivotValueComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  AggregatedComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  // this is a computed default generated using
  PivotComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  // the ExpanderComponent and PivotValueComponent at run-time in methods.js
  PaginationComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  PreviousComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  NextComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  LoadingComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  NoDataComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  ResizerComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element]),
  PadRowComponent: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.func, PropTypes.element])
}
```

and the webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './Scripts/App.js',
    ],
  output: {
    filename: 'Scripts/ReactBundle/bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.Webpack.js', '.web.js', '.js', '.jsx'],
    mainFields: ["main"]
  },
  module: {
      rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',               
            query:
                  {
                      presets: ['react', 'es2017', 'es2015', 'stage-2'],
                      plugins: ['transform-class-properties']
                  }
        },
      ]
  },  
}
```

This doesn't break the code from executing, it merely prevents me from browsing the source or seeing things properly in debuggers, but I'd greatly appreciate any insight as to what's going on.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this problem and after poking around in the package I imported the table like this:

`import ReactTable from 'react-table/lib'`

It looks like that contains the transpiled ES6 without the import syntax that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Update: address asker's comment.

If you're using webpack (most likely with `babel`), make sure [`resolve.mainFields`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields) is not set to anything other than `main`. I'm wonder why the browser is complaining about the `import` syntax when that should have been transpiled out by `babel`. On `npm`, the `prop-types` package declares its [`main` entry](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/7cc8c81d3aed103757f87f02a19baa16fe101bec/package.json) to be `index.js`, which is a CommonJS module. If `webpack` is bundling that file, it should've been able to handle `prop-types`.

---

Original:

Are you running your code through a bundler like webpack? If you're using `script` tags to get `prop-types` onto your page, you need to use the [prebuilt JS file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types#cdn).

The `import ReactTable from "react-table"` line doesn't work because that's ES module and to use ES module in chrome, you need to mark it with the `type="module"` attribute.

Comment: I am using webpack as a bundler, and it's the `import PropTypes from 'prop-types'` that's in error, not `import ReactTable from "react-table"`

Comment: No dice i'm afraid. I edited the question to include my webpack.config file as well.